# How to upload photos and other files in OpenStack Object Storage(Swift)

Tags: java, android, api, openstack, openstack-swift

I'm making an Android Application 
and trying to store files, e.g. docx, music, photos, videos in `OpenStack` object storage(Swift) using it's API.But I'm having a problem in storing these files. From the API that I got, it only stores the name of the file but the object itself is missing when i try to download it from the dashboard.

The API I got from `OpenStack` Documentations is this.

**Method:** PUT
**Link:**  (mylink)/v1/AUTH_(account)/(container)/(object)

**HEADER**
Content-type:  (required)
X-Auth-Token:  (required)
Content-Length: (optional)
ETag:(optional)
Content-Disposition: (optional)
Content-Encoding: (optional)
X-Delete-At: (optional)
X-Object-Meta-PIN:
X-Delete-After:
X-Object-Meta

**BODY**
None

The first file that I tried to upload is a photo, I tried sending it as binary(base64) because base also in the API it only accepts strings. I'm not sure where to put it, so I tried pushing it in Content-Disposition but it failed. I'm not sure where else can i put the photo on the limited data that can be accepted by openstack.

Please help.
I want to view the file that I have uploaded from phone and download it from dashboard.

This is my code:

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPut httpost = new HttpPut("mylink/v1/AUTH_fa6362c6520449f9a8905e84fee68f8c/photos/"+imagename);
        try {   
              httpost.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", "nasbfdblfdfsdfsdfd123a");              
              httpost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");    
              httpost.setHeader("Content-Length ", Integer.toString(binaryimagelength) );   
              httpost.setHeader("Content-Disposition ",  binaryimage);// this is path of the image from the phone memory (e.g. )    

             Log.i("", "pushing your data");    

             HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httpost);
             ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
             String response2 = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
             Log.i("", "Response1:   " + response.getStatusLine());
             Log.i("", "Response2:   " + response2);


        }catch (IOException e) {                    
            Log.e("", "IOException " + e.toString());
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT).create();
             alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
             alertDialog.setMessage(e.toString());
             alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   // TODO Add your code for the button here.

                }
             });
             alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, You specified content-disposition as file path.

> Try to make specify file object there.
>   That is you read file from file path and set content-disposition with fileReadObject.

Note: I am python guy. If you wish I can explain with python code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried putting the specific object there as you have suggested. This is my code:
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);  
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 

I put httppost.setHeader("Content-Type": b), but it doesn't allow anything that is not string.Do you have a sample code format that read file from file path and sets content-disposition with fileReadObject?

Comment: can you convert ByteArray to String like BufferedReader?

Comment: @SyedHabibM Can you look at my question. Its in python and I have a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786418/openstack-rest-api-send-a-file-with-python-to-a-openstack-container?noredirect=1#comment53414361_32786418

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the request body.

Something like:

`httpost.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File(binaryimage)));`

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question, and you inspired me to do my own code, so here it is, I hope it works for you

```
public int uploadToSwift(String filePath, String container) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    String fileName = file.getName();
    long binaryLength = file.length();
    int statusCode;

    // Start http communications
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    System.out.println("Communicating to: http://"+IP+"/v1/AUTH_e3fb300a1a1d48d49fb6512658eaebf5/"+container+"/"+fileName);
    HttpPut httpost = new HttpPut("http://"+IP+":8080/v1/AUTH_e3fb300a1a1d48d49fb6512658eaebf5/"+container+"/"+fileName);
    try {   
          httpost.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", openStackToken);              
          httpost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");    
          httpost.setHeader("Content-Length ", Long.toString(binaryLength) );
          httpost.setEntity(new FileEntity(file));
         System.out.println("Sending your data: " + fileName);    

         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
         statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
         // A file was placed on the container
         if(statusCode == 201){
             System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
             Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
             for(Header header : headers)
                 System.out.println(header.getName() + " " + header.getValue());
         } else {
             System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
         }

    }catch (IOException e) {                    
        System.out.println("IOException " + e.toString());
        return 500;
    } 
    return statusCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can upload file by this code

```
public void uploadFileSmart(MyAsyncTask<Object, Integer, Boolean> task, Uri selectedFile, String parentId)
        throws IOException, NoInternetConnectionException, NotLoggedInException, UnexpectedStatusCodeException,
        FileNotFoundException, UnauthorizedException {

    if (!Utils.isNetworkConnected(context)) {
        throw new NoInternetConnectionException();
    }

    if (!isLoggedin) {
        throw new NotLoggedInException();
    }

    InputStream fis = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedFile);

    // TODO: do get filename and filesize in a functions.
    String fileName = "";
    long fileSize = 0;
    String scheme = selectedFile.getScheme();
    if (scheme.equals("file")) {
        File file = new File(selectedFile.getPath());
        fileName = file.getName();
        fileSize = file.length();
    } else if (scheme.equals("content")) {

        String[] proj = {"_data"};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedFile, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            File file = new File(cursor.getString(0));
            fileName = file.getName();
            fileSize = file.length();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Can't retrieve path from uri: " + selectedFile.toString());
        }
    }

    /*
    if (fileName.length() == 0 || fileSize == 0) {
        throw new IOException("File name is empty or file size is 0.");
    }
    */

    String path = "/stacksync/files";
    List<Pair<String, String>> params = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
    params.add(new Pair<String, String>("file_name", fileName));
    params.add(new Pair<String, String>("overwrite", Boolean.TRUE.toString()));

    if (parentId != null) {
        params.add(new Pair<String, String>("parent", parentId));
    }

    String urlString = Utils.buildUrl(storageURL, path, params);

    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.i(TAG, "Uploading file: " + urlString);

    // Open a connection to that URL.
    HttpsURLConnection ucon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    ucon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    ucon.addRequestProperty(FilesConstants.X_AUTH_TOKEN, authToken);
    ucon.addRequestProperty(FilesConstants.STACKSYNC_API, "True");

    // this timeout affects how long it takes for the app to realize
    // there's a connection problem
    ucon.setReadTimeout(connectionTimeout);

    ucon.setDoOutput(true);

    ucon.connect();

    OutputStream os = ucon.getOutputStream();

    BufferedInputStream bfis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    int total = 0;
    int lastUpdated = 0;
    int percent = 0;

    while ((len = bfis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        total += len;
        percent = (int) (total * 100 / fileSize);
        if (lastUpdated != percent) {
            task.setProgress(percent);
            lastUpdated = percent;
        }

        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    task.setProgress(100);

    // clean up
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    bfis.close();

    int statusCode = ucon.getResponseCode();

    if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) {
        Log.i(TAG, "upload completed in " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");

    } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
        isLoggedin = false;
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected status code: " + statusCode);
        throw new UnexpectedStatusCodeException("Status code: " + statusCode);
    }
}
```

to more visit https://github.com/stacksync/android library