# Openstack Rest API send a file with python to a openstack container

Tags: python, python-requests, openstack, openstack-swift

I am trying to upload a video file to Openstack container using REST API.
This is my Python code to upload to the server.

```
res = requests.put(publicURL+'/'+output_container_name+'/'+toUpload,
            headers={'X-Auth-Token': token},
            files={'file': open(toUpload,'rb')})
```

All the variables that you see in code are defined. In fact I can see my file uploaded to the container but when I download it, I cannot play the video.
When I open the video file with a text editor I see these headers at the beginning and at the end of the file.

```
--0b2e78b52dad4b45a43575c1c42b0b9d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="input_output.mp4"
.
.
. Normal video content
.
.
--0b2e78b52dad4b45a43575c1c42b0b9d--
```

How can I get rid of these header in the file?

EDIT: Even when I remove the headers manually there is still some differences in the files when I check them with diff. The Differences are not visible visually the number of lines are the same and everything look the same.

Comment: Try passing `requests.put()` the  `Content-Type: video/mp4` header.

Comment: @mrnick Tried it the headers are still there

Answer (score 1):

Give the Python OpenStack SDK a try.

```
pip install openstacksdk
```

The code for uploading a file.

```
import sys

from openstack import connection
from openstack import profile
from openstack import utils

utils.enable_logging(True, stream=sys.stdout)

prof = profile.Profile()
prof.set_region(prof.ALL, "RegionOne")

conn = connection.Connection(
    auth_url='https://my.identity.endpoint/v2.0/',
    profile=prof,
    username="my_username",
    password="my_password")

c = conn.object_store.create_container(name='videos')
obj = conn.object_store.create_object(container=c.name,
                                      name='input_output.mp4',
                                      data=open('input_output.mp4', 'r'),
                                      content_type='video/mp4')
print(obj)
```

More info that might be helpful too:

- http://python-openstacksdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openstacksdk